# Deploy Strapi on AWS - ERROR: "Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?"

Tags: javascript, linux, amazon-web-services, deployment, strapi

I'm trying deploy Strapi on AWS, but when I'm launching pm2, then I'm getting error:
"Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?".

Below you can find screenshot with Inbounds/Outbounds settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3GIO.png)

Comment: Are your instances and database on the same VPC?

Comment: I think so... I just created instance of EC2 with application and database (postgres) with RDS.

Comment: Okay, I checked it out. They're on the same VPC

Comment: Also check that your database credentials are correct.